# Dialog with outside touchable

Tags: android, dialog

In an android application, I want to display a `Dialog` on screen and in the same time to allow user to click on the application's UI when the the `Dialog` is open 
can this be done?

if no, what can I use instead of `Dialog`?

Comment: I can't see how that would work using a regular Dialog. An alternative is a Toast, but just for displaying small messages.

Comment: you need to create dialog box isn't

Comment: no this will not work because the dialog contains images

Comment: I guess you mean Dialog, not Dialogue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `Dialog`. But you can do it with `PopupWindow` using `PopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);`.

Answer (score 3):

Showing up a dialog over your Activity, will make your Activity go into onPause() so you won't be able to actually handle things inside that activity anymore until the dialog is dismissed.

If you want to have some view, overlay your original activities view you'll be looking for into the direction of FrameViews, which can overlap other Views.